# Keep explorer file transfer window open when completed (100%)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer

When I copy a large file with Windows Explorer, I want to keep the file transfer window when the transfer is complete.

Can I do that?

Comment: No. You could take a screenshot.